# Sorted Doubly linked circular list // java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have a problem with finding elements in Sorted Doubly Linked circular list. I need to find count of values in list that are between 0 and 10. // [0;10]. 
The problem is that it doesn't allow me to ask for itv() from main class.

```
case 2 :
   System.out.println("[0;20] = "+ list.itv() +" \n");
   break;
```

it shows error. How can i fix that?

```
    public void itv (){
        Node ptr = start;
        int size=0;
        size = getSize();
        int c = 0;
        while (size != 0){
            if(ptr.getData() >=0 && ptr.getData() <=20) {
                c++;
            }
            ptr = ptr.getLinkNext();
            size--;
        }
        System.out.println("[0;20] = " + c);
    }
```

Comment: `itv()` returns void make it return string or some other value to be able to print it between two strings.

Comment: thats because your `itv()` method is `void`. change `void` to `int` and instead of printing `c` you should `return` it.

Comment: Fixed it by using case 2: itv(); break;

Comment: Side note: instead of using `size` in the loop you could loop until `ptr` becomes null. That way you could remove 3 lines in your code and it would also make it more robust.

Comment: who's down-voting this guy into oblivion?  It's his first post and he's trying -- cut him some slack.

Comment: You need to share more of your code.   Where is getSize() defined

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns void. Either return a string like so:

```
public string itv()
{
  Node ptr = start;
        int size=0;
        size = getSize();
        int c = 0;
        while (size != 0){
            if(ptr.getData() >=0 && ptr.getData() <=20) {
                c++;
        }
        ptr = ptr.getLinkNext();
        size--;
        }
        //This line changes
        return "[0;20] = " + c;
}
```

**OR** in the main print before and after calling like so, and without doing the above change:

```
System.out.print("[0;20] = ");
list.itv(); //List.itv() still has System.out.println(...)
break;
```